# Open API (Swagger) route naming convention

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, swagger, openapi

I use Swagger in a project and I am wondering what is the correct route naming convention. On the other hand, I use the following naming convention by using method names, but I am not sure if it is a good practice or not. In this example, I do not follow any convention, just try to use method names so that it should be explanatory for the API page.

Please note that, when I just use `[HttpGet]` and `[HttpGet("{id}")]` for `Get` and `GetById` methods, I encounter error like using the same name twice. For this reason I have to use route annotation as extra. What is the proper way regarding to this issue?

```
[HttpGet, Route("get")]
public IEnumerable<DemoDto> Get()
{
    //
}

[HttpGet, Route("getById/{id}")]
public DemoDto GetById(int id)
{
    //
}

[HttpGet, Route("getWithPagination/{query}")]
public ActionResult<PaginatedList<DemoDto>> GetWithPagination([FromQuery] GetPublishersWithPaginationQuery query)        
{
    //
}

[HttpPost, Route("create/{command}")]
public int Create(Command command)
{
    //
}

[HttpPut, Route("update/{id}")]
public ActionResult Update(int id)
{
    //
}

[HttpDelete, Route("delete/{id}")]
public ActionResult Delete(int id)
{
    //
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally I would follow the naming convention of the language and there is documentation from the creators of the language on what they use so you are consistent with the rest of the community. In this case, [these](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/naming-guidelines) are what Microsoft has documented for C#.

For your other question on routing, typically what I've seen is [attribute routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2), which is what you are using. I haven't tried `HttpGet("{id}")` as I would have done what you ended up doing with `HttpGet, Route("{id}")`.

I think what you have is good practice. You can always ask your team lead if there is an adopted naming practice or look through other projects on repository to see if there already is an established naming convention.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your useful explanation. **#1** As you suggested, I also follow the naming conventions from the pages of the related technology. But this time, it is also related to Swagger, and there seems to be not a proper page for that according to my search. **#2** Your attribute routing link is also very useful. But I am not sure if `[Route("api/books/{id}", Name="GetBookById")]` is the most suitable option for my situation (maybe using this annotation, I can use the same method names in the Name parameter.

Comment: **#3** There is no Team Lead having experience about this issue and that's why I ask you :) So, my usage may not be a good practice. Because I use method names as api parameter. So, should I follow something like `[Route("api/books/{id}", Name="GetBookById")]` ?

Comment: This is just my personal experience but I would say in terms of the routing, you could improve by adding the name so it's easier to distinguish or if you want that metadata. At my company, we haven't standardized it either so some of the routes have `Name=blahblah` while others do not so it does not make much of a difference.  
  
Write what you feel comfortable with and if you feel really strongly about it, see if you could write up a standard. As long as there aren't any glaringly odd syntax, my team focuses on results than the style of the code.